# Unable to launch whatsapp from flutter app

Tags: android, flutter

whatsappp launcher could not launch says null flutter? i want to launch   whatsapp with a phone number that i send in inkwell function ,but from this function it return null.

```
 InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          // Change the color to blue when tapped
                          containerColorW = Color(0xFF78C1F3);
                        });

                        // Your logic for handling the tap (e.g., opening WhatsApp)
                        final call = 'wa:me:${widget.customerModel.phoneNumber}';
                        _launchWhatsApp(call);

                        // Delayed reset to the original color after 2 seconds (2000 milliseconds)
                        Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1500), () {
                          setState(() {
                            containerColorW = Colors.white;
                          });
                        });
                      },...


  _launchWhatsApp(String url) async {
    final whatsappUrl =url; //'sms:$widget.customerModel.phoneNumber'; //"whatsapp://send?phone=${widget.customerModel.phoneNumber}";
    try {
      if (await canLaunchUrl(Uri.parse(whatsappUrl))) {
        await launchUrl(Uri.parse(whatsappUrl));
      } else {
        print("Could not launch WhatsApp");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error launching WhatsApp: $e");
    }

  }
```

Comment: The link passed to the _launchWhatsApp should be `whatsapp://send?...` but in your code it's `wa:me:`. What do you have in the whatsappUrl variable?